# Obfuscate or remove source from Python Wheel?

Tags: python, package, python-wheel

I want to distribute python code in packages, however it is proprietary code that will be stored on client's servers so I do not wish to share the source.

Is it possible to produce a Python Wheel with obfuscated code or removed code?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1943/what-are-the-techniques-and-tools-to-obfuscate-python-programs) also.

Comment: Worth looking at this pyc->py decompiler if you were ever under the impression that pyc protects your code: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/uncompyle